# Triggered Send Monitoring - Failure to Load to DataExtension

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

My company has set up our transactional (order confirmation, ship confirmation) emails using triggered sends.  We ran into an issue a couple days ago where a field length from the calling application was longer than the field length in the associated data extension.  Because the message was successfully loaded to the queue, the calling application received a success response (and proceeded as if everything processed successfully).  We identified the issue by calling the delivery status by request ID (Error: The value specified for a data extension field does not match the field type).

I'm hoping to build some proactive monitoring to provide visibility to this issue in the future without having to make the API call to check the status on each request_id.

I'm trying to use the triggeredsendsummary API.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to pick up this specific error.  Here's where I would expect to see it -

My question - has anyone had any success monitoring triggered messages for all error types?  Is there somehow I can introduce proactive monitoring for this and all other types of errors that might occur for triggered messages?

*Don't mind the high bounce count - this was test data, that is expected.

[image]

Comment: I've had a case open about undocumented error conditions on successful triggered send calls since April 8th.

Comment: Thanks @AdamSpriggs - I've opened a case as well.  Let's hope we can get some traction on this one.  This is blocking our ability to monitor triggered send status at a summary level to quickly identify and correct issues with these critical sends.

Comment: Have you looked at using the Transactional Messaging API and consuming the webhooks?

Comment: We have - as our business users like to change the transactional message content often, we decided to use triggered messages to provide them with a better UI that allows them to self serve.  The transactional messaging API requires a lot of API calls for config and content changes.